# When would SharedPreferences apply() and commit() fail?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using SharedPreferences to persist user's data in my application.
I know the difference between `commit()` and `apply()` methods, but I've noticed that `commit()` returns *true if the new values were successfully written to persistent storage* and `apply()` does not.

What are the reasons that could cause a `commit()` method to return false or a `apply()` method to fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look at [the source code for commit()](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#commit):

```
    public boolean commit() {
        MemoryCommitResult mcr = commitToMemory();
        SharedPreferencesImpl.this.enqueueDiskWrite(
            mcr, null /* sync write on this thread okay */);
        try {
            mcr.writtenToDiskLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
        notifyListeners(mcr);
        return mcr.writeToDiskResult;
    }
```

In other words, `commit()` will return false if the thread is interrupted while waiting for the disk write to finish, or if the disk write fails for some reason (most likely because the disk was full).

Comment: Ok thanks it's more clear now. Does this have to do whit your overall phone available memory or is it more like a piece of memory assigned specifically to this app? Im just wandering if it is more probable to fail if your phone's memory is full.

Comment: This would be the disk utilization of the user's /data partition, where APKs and app-private data is stored. Depending on the device (I think), this may be a shared partition with the "internal storage", i.e. photos and stuff. AFAIK, there is no per-app limit.